# Proving The Derivative Operator Is Unbounded On $C^{\infty}_0(\overline{\Omega})$ With $L^2$ Norm

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals, uniform-convergence

$\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a non-empty, bounded, connected open set with smooth boundary here. Edit: for clarity, by $C^{\infty}_0(\overline{\Omega})$  I mean the smooth functions which vanish on $\partial \Omega$.

Take $n=1$. It's easy to find elementary functions $f_n\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ so that $(\|f_n'\|_{L^2})/(\|f_n\|_{L^2})\to \infty$. Is there a simple choice of even elementary functions $f_n\in C^{\infty}_0([-1,1])$ with the same property? If so, then I suppose one could use polar coordinates $F_n(r,\vec{\theta})=f_n(r)$ to generalize to $\Omega = B_n(0,1)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, and then use a translation with dilation transformation to generalize to arbitrary open balls, and hence arbitrary $\Omega$. Is that correct? Under the assumption it is, it suffices to find the required functions for the case $\Omega = (-1,1)$.

I was thinking of modifying the standard bump function $$f_n(x)=\Phi_n(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-1/(1-x^{2n})} & \text{if } x \in (-1,1)\\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases};$$ numerical calculations indicate $\|f_n\|^2_{L^2}\to 2e^{-2}$ and $\|f'_n\|^2_{L^2}/\|f_n\|^2_{L^2}-n\to 0$, so I'd be done if I proved both claims. I think I've worked out the almost uniform convergence $f_n\to e^{-1}\chi_{[-1,1]}$ to prove the first part, but I'm not quite sure about the latter. It is equivalent to showing
$$\int_{-1}^1 2m\frac{x^{2(m-1)}}{(1-x^m)^4}e^{-2/(1-x^m)}dx \to 2e^{-2} = \int_{-1}^1 e^{-2} dx$$ as $n\to \infty$, where $m=2n$. Is there an easy way to prove this? I'm not sure if we again have almost uniform convergence. If you are certain proving the claim would be messy, can you come up with a simpler choice of $f_n$? (I would like them to be elementary functions.)

Comment: if I understand correctly, your integral is  $\frac Cn\| f_n' \|_{L^2}^2$, which means the two limits are not quite equivalent: it could be that $ \| f_n' \|_{L^2}^2 \sim Cn + \sqrt n$, then $\frac Cn\| f_n' \|_{L^2}^2 \to C$ but $\| f_n' \|_{L^2}^2 - Cn \to \infty$. In any case if you post another question specifically about your specific sequence, do link back to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know most of the question is about your sequence, but do you mind if I give you a slightly different sequence to prove the statement in the title?

In $\mathbb R^d$, without loss of generality, assume $B_2(0)\subseteq\Omega$ (true up to translations and dilations). Consider $f(x)=\Phi_1(x)$ as in your definition (by taking $|x|$ instead of $x$, so it is well-defined in all dimensions). Define $$f_k(x)=f(kx).$$
From the definiiton of $\Phi$, it is clear that the support of $f_k$ equals $\overline B_{1/k}(0)$, so $f_k\in C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ for all $k$. By explicit calculations (using the change of variables $x\mapsto y=kx$), it holds
$$ \|f_k\|_{L^2}=k^{-d/2}\|f\|_{L^2}, $$
$$ \|\partial_{x_j}f_k\|_{L^2}=k^{-d/2+1}\|\partial_{x_j}f\|_{L^2}. $$
So, the ratio $\|\partial_{x_j}f_k\|_{L^2}/\|f_k\|_{L^2}$ diverges as $k$ goes to infinity, so the operator cannot be bounded. This proof works uniformly well on all $\mathbb R^d$, $d\geq 1$.

This is a standard *scaling argument* that comes useful in many interesting settings. The core idea is that when you dilate functions by a factor of $k$, different Lebesgue or Sobolev norms scale as a different power of $k$.

Comment: Ah, of course! I even mentioned transforming by dilation, which implicitly assumed something similar, but somehow missed this. So for $B=B_d(p,r)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$, would $f_k=f\circ g_k$ where $g_k(\vec{x})=(k/r)(\overrightarrow{x-p})$ for $k\geq \lceil r \rceil$ work? Fairly sure $f_k$ is smooth by explicitly writing it out as $\Phi(|g_k(\cdot)|)$, and is supported in $B$ by choice of $k$; since translations don't affect the Jacobian, $k$ in your answer is replaced by $k/r$, and an analogous result follows.

Comment: Yep! It seems it works. That is what I meant when I assumed $B_2(0)\subset \Omega$.

Comment: Great! I will accept your answer since I was completely okay with alternative $f_n$'s that show the result with even less work. I am still curious about my sequence, but perhaps that deserves a separate question now...